# Как сравнить два объекта класса?

Tags: java

У меня есть 2 объекта класса Request

```
public class Request implements Comparable<Request>{

    private Site site = new Site();
    private Visitor visitor = new Visitor();
    private Region region = new Region();
    private AdPlace adPlace = new AdPlace();
    private DateTime date = new DateTime();

    //-----===== getter и setter всех полей ====-----
}
```

Мне нужно сравнить, написать компаратор. По времени уже сравнил, как сравнить по другим полям? Все остальные поля - это enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.9) при сравнении `enum` вполне применим оператор как `==` так и метод `equals()`

> Because there is only one instance of
> each enum constant, it is permissible
> to use the == operator in place of the
> equals method when comparing two
> object references if it is known that
> at least one of them refers to an enum
> constant. (The equals method in Enum
> is a final method that merely invokes
> super.equals on its argument and
> returns the result, thus performing an
> identity comparison.)

Comment: И еще такой вопрос - мне нужно отсортировать ArrayList<Request>
Отсортировать нужно по всем полям.
В классе Request прописал метод compareTo, в котором сравниваю только по полю date.
вообще этот метод должен возвращать только 0(т.е. когда элементы равны) или должно быть полное сравнение: -1(первый элем меньше второго), 1 (первый элем больше второго), 0(элементы равны)

Comment: ну так вот и определи все условия для больше, меньше и равны

Answer (score 0):

По вопросу 2.

Если вы имплементируете `Comparable<>`, то можете написать только 1 `compareTo()`, т.е. сортировать по одному полю. Для сортировки по любому другому полю вы должны использовать версию сортировки с компаратором.

Соответственно, для каждого желаемого поля создавать свой компаратор (`Comparator`) и скармливать его методу `sort()`. Все методы сравнения так и названы (`compare()` или `compareTo`), потому что сравнивают, т.е. отвечают на вопрос "кто больше или меньше или равны", поэтому надо прописывать условия для всех случаев.

Не путайте с `equals()`, который проверяет условия, при которых объекты равны, но не отвечает на вопрос кто больше или меньше.

Comment: Хоть по всем полям сравнивать в методе `compareTo()`.